# I've made recursive moving average filter without using conv function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion, moving-average

Due to some reason, I've had to made recursive moving average filter without using conv function in Matlab. Could you give me some advice to improve my code? My advisor said that this is not a recursive function and I cannot totally understand his word. Please help me

```
function out  = mva(x,h);
    m=length(x); %Length of input signal
    n=length(h); %Length of window
    X=[x,zeros(1,n)]; %Make x and h same length vector X,H
    H=[h,zeros(1,m)]; 
    for i=1:n+m-1 %Create output vector
       if i == 1
         Y(1) = (X(1)*H(1))/n;
       elseif i <= n
         Y(i) = Y(i-1)+X(i)/n;
       else
          Y(i) = Y(i-1)+X(i)/n-X(i-n)/n; 
       end
 out = Y;
 end
```

Comment: I suggest you contact your advisor to have them explain themselves more clearly. That's their job.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It's missing at least one `end`. Is the confusion perhaps between the words "recursive" and "[recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)"? The two are related (see link), but a "recursive function" in computer science is generally distinct from a "recurrence relation." I'm not sure if we can help. If there are problems wit the code please ask a specific question, give the inputs, outputs (and/or expected outputs), and provide any error messages.

Comment: Your advisor doesn't know what he's talking about.  This is a correct implementation of a moving average filter, despite some syntax errors.  You can take my word for it as I used to be a part-time instructor for signal processing courses.  This is correctly referring to past samples.  As what horchler said, this is a recurrence relation, not a recursive relation.

Comment: There is no recursion! Why aren't you using convolution (with the 1 in H shifted)? it's for optimization reasons?

Comment: A recursive function is a function that is calling itself. You do not really do that here since you are not calling `mva` inside the function itself. However, you is using recurrance in the function as already explained.

Comment: Problem solved Thanks I had a confusion with recursive and recurrance